# How can I make POST call to a server using HTTPS on Android

Tags: java, android, post, https, ssl-certificate

I have a custom certificate on Android and need to know how to attach it to make the post call. I have already made successful POSTs using HTTP, but I do not know what steps to take with HTTPS. How do I load the certificate?

Comment: Nothing special is needed for http vs https, just change the url.

Comment: @GabeSechan: The question is about using a custom certificate. Merely changing the URL will not address that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `minSdkVersion` is 24 or higher, you can use Android 7.0's [network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html) to handle this. You package your certificate as a `raw` resource, create an XML resource indicating to use that certificate, and add an attribute in the manifest to teach Android to use those rules.

If your `minSdkVersion` lower than 24, but 17 or higher, you can use [my backport of the network security configuration code](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-netsecurity).

If your `minSdkVersion` is lower than 17, you will need to follow conventional Java instructions for using self-signed certificates. The details of how to do that will vary by HTTP client API that you are using (`HttpURLConnection`, OkHttp, etc.). For example, [this blog post](http://jebware.com/blog/?p=340) outlines how to do that for OkHttp.